# Get dropped mail message from Apple Mail in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I googled and read docs. Searched on SO, found answers that propose usage of Applescript, but I can't use Applescript because of sandbox.

I am working on Cocoa application (written in Objective-C and sandboxed). I am implementing drag-and-drop from Apple Mail application. App should receive or copy eml mail message as Finder does.

I tried looking at `NSPromisedFilesPboardType` but hardly could figure out how I should work with it. I tried such code in `- (BOOL)acceptDrop:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)info` method:

```
if ([info.draggingPasteboard.types containsObject:@"MV Super-secret message transfer pasteboard type"]) {
    NSURL *tempFolder = [FM createTempFolderInFolder:AppDataDir()];
    NSArray *filenames = [info namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:tempFolder];
    // tempFolder is filepath of generated temp folder in appdata directory so it is accessible for sandboxed app
    // filenames becomes nil
    return YES;
}
```

When I try iterating through all types in pasteboard, that what I see:

```
Dropped types are:
Type: dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8y4zvanr41a3pwfz30n25wqz4ca5pfsr30c35feb4he2pssrxgn6vasbu1g7dfqm10c6xeeb4hw6df (null)
Type: MV Super-secret message transfer pasteboard type (null)
Type: dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8zg7puqz3c465fqr3gn7bakf41k55rqf4g86vasbu1g7dfqm10c6xeeb4hw6df (
        {
        account = Gmail;
        id = 6622;
        mailbox = INBOX;
        subject = "got SUV?";
    }
)
Type: Super-secret Automator pasteboard type (
        {
        account = Gmail;
        id = 6622;
        mailbox = INBOX;
        subject = "got SUV?";
    }
)
Type: dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yc6durvwwa3xmrvw1gkdusm1044pxqyuha2pxsvw0e55bsmwca7d3sbwu (
    eml
)
Type: Apple files promise pasteboard type (
    eml
)
Type: public.url (null)
Type: CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x75726C20 (null)
Type: dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yc6durvwwaznwmuuha2pxsvw0e55bsmwca7d3sbwu (
    "message:%3C1a392cb9-b78c-402d-8d7f-dbd1d4a9ec42@Neptune.do.losaltos.k12.ca.us%3E",
    ""
)
Type: Apple URL pasteboard type (
    "message:%3C1a392cb9-b78c-402d-8d7f-dbd1d4a9ec42@Neptune.do.losaltos.k12.ca.us%3E",
    ""
)
Type: public.url-name (null)
Type: CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x75726C6E (null)
Type: com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-content-type com.apple.mail.email
Type: com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-url (null)
Type: dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8y6y4usm1044pxqzb085xyqz1hk64uqm10c6xenv61a3k (null)
Type: NSPromiseContentsPboardType (null)
```

Anyone could help me?

Comment: I'm doing something similar. Did you ever find an acceptable way to do this?

Comment: @ArrMiHardies no, never found anything what worked and just decided not to care

Answer (score 3):

I just went through this process and it was pretty easy actually.

Look for "com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-content-type = com.apple.mail.email" in the pasteboard types and if found simply call namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination (from NSDraggingInfo) with the drop destination URL and the file will be created when the drag is finished.

Comment: That just seems to give us the name of the file but not the actual path. That will also create a copy of the email in a temporary folder. Not sure if that's what we want? Did you find a way to directly point to the email file on disk?

Comment: I don't think the "actual file" does exist on disk. It's probably just an entry in a database so referencing it as a file which will instruct Mail.app to open that message is as good as it gets.