# Reproducing Mac Mail / TextEdit interaction

Tags: macos, email, nsurl, textedit, nspasteboard

TextEdit has this great treatment of messages dragged from the Mac Mail app — the subject line transfers as a hyperlink that when clicked opens the original message in Mail.  Any thoughts how I could do the same in my app?  Not having much luck with NSPasteboard; the data doesn't seem to transfer as NSURL's or NSString's.  I don't think the data is totally obscure, though, as dragging a Mail message to Microsoft Word does transfer over a file URL, albeit one that doesn't open successfully.

Comment: "Do the same in my app" means dragging from Mail? I.e., do the same _as TextEdit_?

Comment: Yes, I'd like the user to be able to drag a message from Mail into my app and have it display the subject line in the same way, as a hyperlink that opens the original Mail message.

Comment: Not sure how to close this as a duplicate, but the following question looks like it will answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765063/get-dropped-mail-message-from-apple-mail-in-cocoa

Comment: Hey, glad you solved it! Just click the "flag" link, and use the "other (needs moderator attention)" box to write a little note that you, the OP, have found another question that answers yours.