# Dropping promised files on to application icon in Dock

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, sandbox, mac-app-store

Is it possible to open promised files `NSFilesPromisePboardType` in sandboxed application when dropping on to application icon in Dock? The Dock icon is accepting the drop, but `-application:openFile:` is never called.

The only reference I found are pre sandbox:
[Accepting iCal events dropped on my application's icon](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/225428-accepting-ical-events-dropped-on-my-application-icon.html)

rdar://47917787

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break this down: `NSApplication` and `NSDocumentController` in  `NSDocument` based apps gives you `-application:openFile:` or `-openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:` for free in case of `NSFilenamesPboardType` and `NSURLPboardType` drops.

Note: I *think* under the hood this is implement with the NSAppleEventManager event handlers for `kCoreEventClass`/`kAEOpenDocuments` and `kInternetEventClass`/`kAEGetURL`.

Unfortunately they don't handle `NSFilesPromisePboardType`.

Lets refresh our pasteboard knowledge: The pasteboard is *shared* amongst all application. There are default pasteboards for tasks like copy, find, and drag.

When the drag starts the application writes into the shared drag pasteboard. So all we need now is notification about the drop onto Dock icon.

This is where `NSService` comes into play:

```
<key>NSServices</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSMessage</key>
        <string>openService</string>
        <key>NSSendTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSMenuItem</key>
        <dict>
            <key>default</key>
            <string>Open</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And set it up in code:

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [NSApp setServicesProvider:self];
}

- (void)openService:(NSPasteboard *)serviceBoard
           userData:(NSString *)userData
              error:(NSString **)error
{
}
```

One caveat is that the `NSService` pasteboard is not the `NSDragPboard` pasteboard.

But they are all shared, so we can just access the one we want:

```
NSPasteboard *dragPboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];

if ([[dragPboard types] containsObject:NSFilesPromisePboardType])
{
}
```

The next problem is that we don't have `-[NSDraggingInfo namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:]`.

```
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
```

Good old Carbon got us covered.

```
    PasteboardRef pboardRef = NULL;
    PasteboardCreate((__bridge CFStringRef)NSDragPboard, &pboardRef);
    PasteboardSetPasteLocation(pboardRef, (__bridge CFURLRef)temporaryDirectory);

    NSString *urlString = [dragPboard stringForType:(NSString *)kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise];

    CFRelease(pboardRef);
```

Handle like any other promise file from here on.

Comment: I would like to drag an email from Mail to my application's Dock icon. I used the code above (added NSService key to my Info.plist file, set the service provider and added the method openService). But the method openService is not called. What can I do?