# drag & drop photos from app "Photos" to third party app under OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-elcapitan

I got a lot of support requests from my Mac App Store apps describing drag & drop photo from Apple's app "Photos"(what a xxxx name they are using as an app!) to my app appears impossible under OS X El Capitan. That was ok in iPhoto ages.

The sandbox settings of my apps are all YES to these entitlements:
    com.apple.security.assets.movies.read-write
    com.apple.security.assets.pictures.read-write
    com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write

What I have to do is asking user drag & drop photos to their desktop first then drag & drop again to my app.

Anyone got this kind of problem for your third party apps and how can we fix it in OUR upgrade?

Comment: You can use a share extension to send it from those app, as seems Apple is doing it themselves.

Comment: Do you mean pop up a Share to menu every time? Any detail please?

Comment: I ment this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1 , but if you want direct drag and drop, it's also do able. I remembered Apple got a page with some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample project to demonstrate how you can do it here:

https://github.com/x43x61x69/Promised-files-Example

Comment: This iOS sample works by using Share Extensions! It should be considered as the the correct answer although the question is related to Mac OS. Thank you Cai!

Answer (score 3):

Currently the Photos app uses File Promises when dragging files. *(There is talk that this maybe will be changed because very few app handle file promises.)*

You find more information about this in [Drag and Drop Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001288-102943).

For dropping promised files on to application icon in Dock see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793386/dropping-promised-files-on-to-application-icon-in-dock/33929541#33929541).

Comment: I am to work on it and will paste the result here if I can make it. Thanks!